# UPDATE statement not consistent when including NULL fields

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, update

So I want to append Field B to C, then copy field A to B and set field A to "Awaiting update".

I have written the following code

```
UPDATE Notes

SET

/* append previous month to notes */
Notes=Notes + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '---' + CAST(GETDATE() as         nvarchar(max)) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(LastMonth as nvarchar(max))

/* replace previous month with current month */
, LastMonth=CurrentNote

/* replace previous month with current month*/
, CurrentNote=cast('To be updated' as nvarchar(max))
```

The problem i've found is that if any of the fields in the row are blank the update statement no longer works as expected.

What is the correct method for going about an update like this?

Comment: What do you mean by blank - NULL?  What does the table definition look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, when you concatenate string, if one part is NULL the result of the string will be NULL. To avoid this behavior, you have to test all your string with the ISNULL function to ensure a string empty instead of the NULL value.

```
UPDATE Notes

SET

/* append previous month to notes */
Notes=ISNULL(Notes,'') + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '---' + CAST(GETDATE() as         nvarchar(max)) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(ISNULL(oppo_rota_last_progress_update,'') as nvarchar(max))

/* replace previous month with current month */
, LastMonth=CurrentNote

/* replace previous month with current month*/
, CurrentNote=cast('To be updated' as nvarchar(max))
```

Comment: In *standard* SQL *any* operation with a NULL results in NULL (except if you consider applying specific functions like `COALESCE`), including comparison, arithmetic, and (as in this case) concatenation. You are not wrong, but your statement holds for much more than SQL Server & string concatenation. Regarding `COALESCE`: you should probably use that rather than `ISNULL` for portability too (`ISNULL` is not part of the standard, `COALESCE` is) unless you are using subqueries inside the function in which case there can be a significant performance difference.

Comment: And you don't **have to** use `ISNULL()`. You could use `COALESCE()` function or a `CASE` expression.

Comment: @David_Spillet I was actually in the process of applying the COALESCE() function when Nico responded, thanks for helping me to understand the reasons for choosing one over the other.